# Probability Density Functions and Existence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Are these true or false for every continuous random variable $X$ with density function $f_X$ and distribution function $F_X$?

($a$) The density function of the random variable $X^2$ is ($f_X)^2$.

I believe this is false, I think I found a counterexample.

($b$) The random variables $X$ and $X^3$ are not independent.

I believe this is false as there must exist some random variable $X$ for which $X$ and $X^3$ are independent.

($c$) If E[$X^2$] exists then E[$X^4$] also exists.

I think this is false.

Comment: For a given $x\in{\mathbb R}$, what is the probability $P((X\le x) \text{and} (X^3 > x^3))$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis $0$?

Comment: Yes, now assuming $X$ and $X^3$ are independent, find another expression involving $F_X$.

Comment: @Gribouillis You multiply the probabilities of each event that you gave right. Would it be $p(1-p)$?

Comment: @Gribouillis Can you tell me which of my statements I have correctly gave the answer too and which ones I have got wrong please ?